# Regex to escape query string otherwise simple redirect issue

Tags: regex

I'm trying to foil bots from registering on my site. The issue is a form that is on a url without a capture. I have a different form with a capture I want to redirect to

I want

```
http://site.com?task=register#content
```

to redirect to

```
http://site.com/home/register
```

Here is what I have so far

`redirect 301 ^task\=register\#content$ http://site.com/home/register`

NOTE : The solution needs to have regex involved because the query string is complex with its characters that need escaping which the slash should be doing.

Thank you.

Comment: What server are you using? Where is this regex going?

Comment: its inside .htaccess Apache server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try doing it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.other.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that its a joomla site and there is other stuff inside this file it should also be noted. I got close with the following 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task\=register$
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.com/home/register [L,R=301]

it does detect the right url but doesnt redirect has an error that it cant complete - could this be to subsequent {QUERY_STRING} rewrite which there is...will now try yours

Comment: hmmm im finding the url and redirecting but the issue is that it is re-attaching the query string on the end

So http://site.com/home/register/?task=register#content 
and I wanted just http://site.com/home/register

So im real close...

Comment: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/

needed a ? at the end

Answer (score 0):

Remove the caret (^), i.e.

```
redirect 301 task\=register\#content$ http://site.com/home/register
```

Comment: the url to capture is actually http://site.com/component/user/?task=register#content

Comment: It needs the regex part due to the query string I am informed but without a solution. This doesn't work but thanks for the effort.